# How to make a Dropdownlist in the header reload the main page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically, I have this webpage that is the header on any page you go to. One of the elements in this header is a drop down list that is populated with customer names. On one of these pages there are text fields that need to update with new data depending on if the user selects a different customer from the drop down list in the header. However, since I am pretty new to web-based programming, I'm not sure what code to put in the header that will make the main page below it reload when the drop down list index is changed. Also, the language this is all in is asp.net and C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP .NET has built in facility to handle this called Master Pages. I'm not sure how you are including your header file now, but with ASP .NET 2.0 Master pages are the way to go.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) to learn how to implement master pages in your web site. Once you have added a master page you can pass data from the master page to the content page via events.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145750/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/013107-1.aspx) article explains how to use events to pass data between content and master pages and vice versa. The example even uses a drop down list.

Comment: Yeah, there is a Master Page in use here. But I'll see if that article can help out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: Setting the `AutoPostBack` property of the `DropDownList` (assuming we're talking about an ASP.NET `DropDownList` control) will trigger a postback when the selected item changes. The `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList` can be used to load new customer info (or whatever).

Now, if the dropdown list is in a master page and you want to deal with change events on your individual web forms, things will get a bit complicated. You might want to declare an event FROM your web form and trigger it on your master page when the dropdown list changes, and then deal with the customer change on on your individual web forms as the situation dictates.

Hopefully this is enough info to get you started.

Answer (score -1):

This is not really an asp.net or C# question.  The dropdown selection occurs in the user's browser, and the server doesn't know anything about it unless you arrange for the page to do something.  A common approach is to use Javascript to attach a function to the dropdown's onChange event, and have that function cause the reload of what you call the main page.  I hope this helps you get started.

Comment: This is an asp:DropDownList object, and it uses OnSelectedIndexChanged() which I am coding in C#. I'm asking how to code this event in C# so that the page reloads and re fetches the data so I don't see how this isn't asp.net or C#?